# c# ToastNotification launch url not in default browser

Tags: c#, toast

I'm using c# ToastNotifications, and I can use the Launch parameter to launch a url in the default web browser. However I want it to launch in firefox which is not the default web browser on the machine. Is it possible to specify in ToastNotification which browser to Launch the url in?

Comment: How would you know for sure that the user has Firefox installed? And if they don't, what would you do then?

Comment: You can attempt to start the `firefox.exe` process with the toast as a command line argument, not sure how well that will work though. [this script](https://gist.github.com/rubenwardy/0b8effeb01e5ce2205ac) follows a similar pattern, might be something you can work with here